# How to learn what is trying to use my DB?

Tags: docker, postgresql

I'm having a working postgre 11.5 in a docker container, they're just fine!

In the the logs I see lots of:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myuser"
DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "myuser".
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
```

how do I get to know what/which process is trying to access my db, especially with wrong credentials?

Comment: Is your database reachable from the internet?

Comment: no, it is reachable as much as it has to.

Comment: Hm, okay. Is the access coming from the same container? Can you at least see which IP and port it is coming from? Is it perhaps a user unique to a single client/program?

Comment: this is what I am asking? how to see this/those IP(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `log_connections = on` in postgresql.conf will log the IP address of the clients.

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html):

> log_connections (boolean)
>
> Causes each attempted connection to the server to be logged, as well as successful completion of client authentication. Only
> superusers can change this parameter at session start, and it cannot
> be changed at all within a session. The default is off.